# Determine if $f(x) = $ $1 \over |x|$ $\in L^p(B_1(0))$ or $L^p(B_1(0)^C)$ or $L^p(B_1(0)^C)$ for any $p$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to determine if $f(x) = $ $1 \over |x|$ $\in L^p(B_1(0))$ or $f(x) = $ $1 \over |x|$ $\in L^p(B_1(0)^C)$ or $f(x) = $ $1 \over |x|$ $\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$  for any value of $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I should note that $B_1(0)$ is the unit ball centered at $0$.

I have tried doing the integral over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and with several values of $p$ and it seems like the function only converges for $p = 2$. It seems like an argument using Holder's inequality might work here, but I'm not sure how to find the appropriate $L^p$ and $L^q$ functions such that $p$ and $q$ form a dual index so that I can use Holder's inequality.

For the integral over $B_1(0)$, it seems like the integral doesn't converge for any $n$ or $p$. I'm not sure how to integrate over $B_1(0)^C$.

Some hints on these problems would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spherical coordinates to calculate the integrals exactly: the surface area of the $n$-ball $B(0,r)$ equals $c_n r^{n-1}$ for some dimensional constant $c_n$ so that

$$\int_{B(0,1)} |x|^{-p} \, dx = \int_0^1 \int_{|x| = r} |x|^{-p} \, dS(x)  dr = \int_0^1 r^{-p} \int_{|x| = r} \, dS(x) dr = c_n \int_0^1 r^{-p} r^{n-1} \, dr$$
and likewise
$$\int_{B(0,1)^C } |x|^{-p} \, dx = c_n \int_1^\infty r^{-p} r^{n-1} \, dr.$$

Unless $p=n$ one of these will converge and one will diverge. If $p=n$ they both diverge.